# Remove richtextbox SelectionBackColor

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How can I change `SelectionBackColor` of richtext box to "no color"?

I tried these:

```
Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
Color.Empty;
Color.White;
Color.Transparent;
```

But they are all return same result: `Color.White` !!!

For more description, change richtextbox backcolor to some color like pink, then change SelectionBackColor to red, now, try to remove `SelectionBackColor`, you see that the color will be white. please note that it is not true to change `SelectionBackColor` to pink in this example :D !!!

Comment: It does not happen here. Can you share more details? Are you referring to text color for selected text?

Comment: I explained completly in question, please create a new c# winform project, add a richtextbox, change it's backcolor to pink (just for testing of selected text backcolor). now add a button, and write this line: richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red; and second button with this code: richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent;
run the code and type something, select a word and press btn1 and then btn2
all text should have same backcolor, but you will see that selected word have white backcolor

Comment: I tried microsoft office word to test it, in highlight submenu, there is a button named 'No Color' and it's working great !!! I want this button :D

Comment: Do you mean by set font color as default. then default color is black. please specify more.

Comment: I'm not talking about font color, I'm talking about font highlight color or "richtextbox.selectionbackcolor", in office word, you can change highlight color to 'No Color' and when you copy the text, it will not have any highlight color! but in C# we can not completely remove backgroundcolor of text (named highlight in word)

Comment: See here for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327153/c-sharp-richtextbox-remove-custom-selectionbackcolor/28426076#28426076

Comment: Although much time has passed, and it is not usefull for me any more, but thanks, and this should be the correct answer. I hope it will be used by other people. thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is not magic

```
richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = richTextBox1.BackColor;
```

valter

Comment: it is like what I said in question, I am saving rtf in sql, and I don't know what will be the color of richtextbox!

Comment: @TYeeTY You said *add a richtextbox, change it's backcolor to pink...*, what sql have to do with anything. You dont need to know the color thats why the code `richTextBox1.BackColor`

Comment: that was just for testing :((( if richtextbox backcolor is white, you could not see what happens. for another example, after your code copy and paste your text in office word and you will see it has highlight color!

Comment: @TYeeTY Now you are saying something new. What **exactly** are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm bad in english, excuse me, I just want to completely remove backgroundcolor of selected text in richtextbox

Comment: @TYeeTY It is easy in c/c++ (intercept the WM_PAINT of the control and if the left mouse button is down use ValidateRect(hwnd, NULL); This function causes the control to not draw anything, hence no selected color) but in c# i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need some clarification on what you mean by "no color".
Do you mean transparent?

You can set the SelectionBackColor back to the default color:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.defaultbackcolor(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionbackcolor(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = DefaultBackColor, it is 'control' color that is something like gray (255,240,240,240) and is not 'no color'

Answer (score 0):

Well i had same problem too, finally i used that code:

```
richTextBox.Text = richTextBox.Text.Replace(richTextBox.SelectedText, richTextBox.SelectedText);
```

this works for background but deletes all other format too (underline, bold etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but i just noticed if you write

```
this.richTextBox.SelectedText = "\r";
```

the RTF loses all formatting for the following texts, including the SelectionBackColor.

e.g.

```
this.richTextBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
this.richTextBox.SelectedText = "the damn yellow backcolor is set";
this.richTextBox.SelectedText = "\r";
this.richTextBox.SelectedText = "now i have transparent backcolor again and the default text";
```