# C# RichTextBox Remove Custom SelectionBackColor

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, backcolor

After having done some research, I believe I am asking the same question as [Remove richtextbox SelectionBackColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359315). I have encountered the same issue, but I believe the answers in that thread were insufficient as the question was not clearly explained. Please see below:

In a `RichTextBox`, how do I **remove** a custom `BackColor` from some, but not all, of the text (`SelectionBackColor`) so that it assumes the `BackColor` of the control **even if that `BackColor` changes in the future?**

I have a method that highlights some text and changes its `BackColor` using `SelectionBackColor`. I have another method that changes the `BackColor` of the entire control. These events can happen independently.

If I want to "remove" some `SelectionBackColor`, I can try to set the `SelectionBackColor` to `Color.Transparent`, but it ends up being White. That is fine, temporarily, if my `RichTextBox`'s **current** `BackColor` is White. If I set `SelectionBackColor` to the current `BackColor`, it is fine temporarily, **until that BackColor changes from another method.**

After the `RichTextBox.BackColor` has changed, any places that were previously highlighted use White or the previous `BackColor`, instead of assuming the new color like text that had not previously highlighted.

I have tried deleting and replacing the text, but that negates the ability to retain any other custom formatting of that text, to my knowledge. Setting `SelectionBackColor` to null does not work.

One can easily see what I am talking about using the code below:

```
protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLostFocus(e);
    this.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    if (SelectionLength > 0)
    {
        SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}

protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnGotFocus(e);
    this.ResetBackColor();
    if (SelectionLength > 0)
    {
        // The goal of this line is to "remove" the yellow.
        // By assigning it any value, it seems to have lost
        // the ability to use the control's BackColor normally.
        SelectionBackColor = this.BackColor;// or Color.Transparent
    }
}
```

Type some text into a custom `RichTextBox` object with the code above, highlight a small portion of it, then make the box lose focus. You will see the highlighted text in yellow. Then, make the box gain focus. The yellow background will go away, as expected. However, if you move your caret elsewhere in the text and make the control lose focus again, you will see the previously-highlighted text does not assume the gray background color.

Comment: How about providing some code to work upon?

Comment: I can't use the original source code as it is on another locked-down work machine. See a simplified example edited in above.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The Colors are values of the text chunks, not references into some space. So you will need to loop through the whole text to change any colors. You may want to peek into the rtf code to see what I mean. (And transparency is not a real color anyway, so it won't help here either..)

Comment: Hm, actually looking at the rtf gives me ideas: There is a Color table but the highlights are different and replacing of of these with another one could be a fast solution; at least if you know what to replace by what..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting.  It appears that (on Windows 7/.Net 3.5 where I tested and perhaps elsewhere) [`System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.SelectionBackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionbackcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may have a bug clearing the selection back color.  The [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,d0f4a24face1b591) does:

```
    public Color SelectionBackColor {
        set
        {
            //Note: don't compare the value to the old value here: it's possible that 
            //you have a different range selected.
            selectionBackColorToSetOnHandleCreated = value;
            if (IsHandleCreated)
            {
                NativeMethods.CHARFORMAT2A cf2 = new NativeMethods.CHARFORMAT2A();
                if (value == Color.Empty)
                {
                    cf2.dwEffects = RichTextBoxConstants.CFE_AUTOBACKCOLOR;
                }
                else
                {
                    cf2.dwMask = RichTextBoxConstants.CFM_BACKCOLOR;
                    cf2.crBackColor = ColorTranslator.ToWin32(value);
                }

                UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, Handle), RichTextBoxConstants.EM_SETCHARFORMAT, RichTextBoxConstants.SCF_SELECTION, cf2);
            }
        }
    }
```

This does not, as you have noticed, actually clear the back color when set to [`richTextBox.BackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2kh9x59%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Nor does it clear the color when set to [`RichTextBox.DefaultBackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.defaultbackcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which simply sets the selection back color to the default grey control color.   It looks as though the source code is *trying to* clear the selection back color when set to `Color.Empty` -- but on my machine at least, it does nothing.

But if I create an extension method that also sets `cf2.dwMask = RichTextBoxConstants.CFM_BACKCOLOR;` for an empty color before sending the message, then `SetSelectionBackColor(Color.Empty)` now works!

```
    public static void SetSelectionBackColor(this RichTextBox richTextBox, Color value)
    {
        if (richTextBox.IsHandleCreated && value == Color.Empty)
        {
            var cf2 = new CHARFORMAT2();

            cf2.dwEffects = RichTextBoxConstants.CFE_AUTOBACKCOLOR;
            cf2.dwMask = RichTextBoxConstants.CFM_BACKCOLOR;
            cf2.crBackColor = ColorTranslator.ToWin32(value);

            UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(richTextBox, richTextBox.Handle), RichTextBoxConstants.EM_SETCHARFORMAT, RichTextBoxConstants.SCF_SELECTION, cf2);
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox.SelectionBackColor = value;
        }
    }
```

Full method, with constants and classes adapted from [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,01299dc795f86748) and [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBoxConstants.cs) and [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,e75041b5218ff60b) and [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs,0d546f58103867e3) and [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/CHARFORMAT2.html):

```
public static class RichTextBoxConstants
{
    // http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBoxConstants.cs,31b52ac41e96a888
    /* EM_SETCHARFORMAT wparam masks */
    internal const int SCF_SELECTION = 0x0001;

    internal const int EM_SETCHARFORMAT = (NativeMethods.WM_USER + 68);

    internal const int CFM_BACKCOLOR = 0x04000000;

    /* NOTE: CFE_AUTOCOLOR and CFE_AUTOBACKCOLOR correspond to CFM_COLOR and
       CFM_BACKCOLOR, respectively, which control them */
    internal const int CFE_AUTOBACKCOLOR = CFM_BACKCOLOR;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public class CHARFORMAT2
{
    // http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,acde044a28b57a48
    // http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/CHARFORMAT2.html

    public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CHARFORMAT2));
    public int dwMask;
    public int dwEffects;
    public int yHeight;
    public int yOffset;
    public int crTextColor;
    public byte bCharSet;
    public byte bPitchAndFamily;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string szFaceName;
    public short wWeight;
    public short sSpacing;
    public int crBackColor;
    public int lcid;
    public int dwReserved;
    public short sStyle;
    public short wKerning;
    public byte bUnderlineType;
    public byte bAnimation;
    public byte bRevAuthor;
    public byte bReserved1;
}

public static class NativeMethods
{
    // http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,e75041b5218ff60b

    public const int WM_USER = 0x0400;

    public static void SetSelectionBackColor(this RichTextBox richTextBox, Color value)
    {
        if (richTextBox.IsHandleCreated && value == Color.Empty)
        {
            var cf2 = new CHARFORMAT2();

            cf2.dwEffects = RichTextBoxConstants.CFE_AUTOBACKCOLOR;
            cf2.dwMask = RichTextBoxConstants.CFM_BACKCOLOR;
            cf2.crBackColor = ColorTranslator.ToWin32(value);

            UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(richTextBox, richTextBox.Handle), RichTextBoxConstants.EM_SETCHARFORMAT, RichTextBoxConstants.SCF_SELECTION, cf2);
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox.SelectionBackColor = value;
        }
    }
}

public static class UnsafeNativeMethods
{
    // http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs,0d546f58103867e3
    // For RichTextBox
    //
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, int msg, int wParam, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] CHARFORMAT2 lParam);
}
```

Comment: I failed to mention that I did try Color.Empty. I am using .NET 4.0 on an XP machine (remember, locked-down work computer) and Color.Empty appears to set it to White. We are migrating to Windows 8 and I may have access to .NET 4.5. Hopefully this issue is simpler to solve after the migration.

Thank your for your hard work on this. I will see about integrating this as a solution while I am still on XP, assuming I can get all of it without subverting company policy.

Comment: @Matthew - I suspect the bug exists on Win8/.Net 4.5 as well, and my fix works there as well, since the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,d0f4a24face1b591) corresponds to the most recent version of .Net and Windows.  Not 100% sure it will work on XP, but it might so give it a try.

Comment: @Matthew - I copied the constants in a block from the reference source and pinvoke.net.  You could probably trim it down to  5 or 6 constants if you need to do so.

Comment: dbc, I was able to implement the necessary pieces to this solution in 51 lines added to my custom RichTextBox class, including five constants, the SetSelectionBackColor funtion, CHARFORMAT2 class and UnsafeNativeMethods class. You are probably correct in that the updated software won't likely be of much help. Regardless, your solution works on XP with .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
SelectionBackColor = default(Color);
```

and it worked fine.