# WinForms: SelectionCharOffset and FontSize

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I want to make `SelectionCharOffset` property of `RichTextBox` dependant on `size of the font` (for instance `SelectionCharOffset = FontSize/(2.2)` ). But as the first one is expressed as integer and the second one is float, then I would have to use an explicit conversion.

And here I've got a problem, because I don't want do that.  That would lead do loss of information and I have to do conversions in both ways, any time I need. I also tried to force the font size to be expressed as integer, but when I set it to 11, let's say, it is always automatically changed to 11.25, etc.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The underlying MFC control stores the `yOffset` in twips, which are 1/1440 of an inch or 1/20 of a printer's point.  See the [CHARFORMAT2 structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883.aspx).  You might be able to create your own extension method `SelectionCharOffsetInTwips` based on the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,cf91f0ae4d8ea3f2) just by skipping the conversion to pixels.

Comment: For an example of how to set up a `CHARFORMAT2` structure for a rich text box through interop, see [C# RichTextBox Remove Custom SelectionBackColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327153/c-sharp-richtextbox-remove-custom-selectionbackcolor/28426076#28426076).

Comment: Do twips have enough precision to meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Internally, the underlying MFC rich edit control stores the [y offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883.aspx) in [twips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip), which are are 1/1440 of an inch or 1/20 of a printer's point.  However, for some reason the [`SelectionCharOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncharoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) hides this level of precision and instead returns in pixels, which are roughly 20 times less precise.  If twips are sufficiently precise to meet your needs, you can create your own extension methods to get and set the `SelectionCharOffset` in twips, modeled on the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,cf91f0ae4d8ea3f2):

```
public static class RichTextBoxNativeMethods
{
    private static CHARFORMAT2 GetCharFormat(this RichTextBox richTextBox, bool fSelection)
    {
        // Either CHARFORMAT or CHARFORMAT2 can be used as long as the cbSize is set correctly.
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774230.aspx

        // Force handle creation
        if (!richTextBox.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            var handle = richTextBox.Handle;
        }

        var cf2 = new CHARFORMAT2();
        UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(richTextBox, richTextBox.Handle), RichTextBoxConstants.EM_GETCHARFORMAT, fSelection ? RichTextBoxConstants.SCF_SELECTION : RichTextBoxConstants.SCF_DEFAULT, cf2);
        return cf2;
    }

    public static void SetSelectionCharOffsetInTwips(this RichTextBox richTextBox, int offsetInTwips)
    {
        // Adapted from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,7765c7694b8e433f

        // Force handle creation
        if (!richTextBox.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            var handle = richTextBox.Handle;
        }

        var cf2 = new CHARFORMAT2();

        cf2.dwMask = RichTextBoxConstants.CFM_OFFSET;
        cf2.yOffset = offsetInTwips;

        UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(richTextBox, richTextBox.Handle), RichTextBoxConstants.EM_SETCHARFORMAT, RichTextBoxConstants.SCF_SELECTION, cf2);
    }

    public static int GetSelectionCharOffsetInTwips(this RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        // Adapted from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBox.cs,7765c7694b8e433f
        int selCharOffset = 0;

        var cf2 = richTextBox.GetCharFormat(true);
        if ((cf2.dwMask & RichTextBoxConstants.CFM_OFFSET) != 0)
        {
            selCharOffset = cf2.yOffset;
        }
        else
        {
            // The selection contains characters of different offsets,
            // so we just return the offset of the first character.
            selCharOffset = cf2.yOffset;
        }

        return selCharOffset;
    }
}

public static class NativeMethods
{
    public const int WM_USER = 0x0400;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public class CHARFORMAT2
{
    // http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,acde044a28b57a48
    // http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/CHARFORMAT2.html
    public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CHARFORMAT2));
    public int dwMask;
    public int dwEffects;
    public int yHeight;
    public int yOffset;
    public int crTextColor;
    public byte bCharSet;
    public byte bPitchAndFamily;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string szFaceName;
    public short wWeight;
    public short sSpacing;
    public int crBackColor;
    public int lcid;
    public int dwReserved;
    public short sStyle;
    public short wKerning;
    public byte bUnderlineType;
    public byte bAnimation;
    public byte bRevAuthor;
    public byte bReserved1;
}

public static class RichTextBoxConstants
{
    // Trimmed down from
    // http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RichTextBoxConstants.cs,31b52ac41e96a888
    /* EM_SETCHARFORMAT wparam masks */
    /* EM_SETCHARFORMAT wparam masks */
    internal const int SCF_SELECTION = 0x0001;
    internal const int SCF_WORD = 0x0002;
    internal const int SCF_DEFAULT = 0x0000;   // set the default charformat or paraformat
    internal const int SCF_ALL = 0x0004;   // not valid with SCF_SELECTION or SCF_WORD
    internal const int SCF_USEUIRULES = 0x0008;   // modifier for SCF_SELECTION; says that
                                                // the format came from a toolbar, etc. and
                                                // therefore UI formatting rules should be
                                                // used instead of strictly formatting the
                                                // selection.

    internal const int EM_SETCHARFORMAT = (NativeMethods.WM_USER + 68);
    internal const int EM_GETCHARFORMAT = (NativeMethods.WM_USER + 58);

    internal const int CFM_BACKCOLOR = 0x04000000;
    internal const int CFM_OFFSET = 0x10000000;

    /* NOTE: CFE_AUTOCOLOR and CFE_AUTOBACKCOLOR correspond to CFM_COLOR and
       CFM_BACKCOLOR, respectively, which control them */
    internal const int CFE_AUTOBACKCOLOR = CFM_BACKCOLOR;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't really answer my question.I want to be able to convert to SelectionCharOffset and in return, without losing information. So it doesn't help if I have my font in twips, while SelectionCharOffset is integer.